# I have compiled a poetry book with poems of 4chan users. It has a lot of vulgarisms, is it possible to publish something like that?

Tags: publishing, book, poetry

It has around 200 poems, a lot of vulgarisms, and many of them seem senseless.

Comment: I suspect most poets would describe their work as "seeming senseless and random to a shallow person who can't see deeper."

Comment: It kinda feels like a 4chan troll is visiting us... do you have the rights to any of these 'poems'?  You can't just compile other people's work and publish it without their permission, obviously...

Comment: No actually I'm not a troll at all. It would be great if the rest of The Internet would stop referring to us as "trolls" too. Also, it's nobodies work, because it's an anonymous imageboard and the threads already got deleted. It would be like saying that Grimm brothers' content wasn't original.

Comment: It is in fact someone else's work.  Someone else wrote it.  If you publish that work and someone claims that they wrote it (and can prove it, maybe through IP logs or having posted it non-anonymously elsewhere), they would have a very good case for infringement.  That is why you would have trouble finding a publisher.

Comment: Also, the Brothers Grimm lived in a time long before copyright and even if copyright had existed, they works they were compiling and publishing would have been long out of copyright with no discernible author. What you are looking to publish has an author and is very much in the era of copyright.

Comment: There is no way to prove who's work was that poem. No technical way, I could officially claim it's all mine, and it would be. Even if you view it from a moral, not a legal perspective, the participants were told that I will probably put them in a book, and that by posting a poem with a correct form they agree to it.

Comment: @Bane This is the internet. You just posted a question and admitted that you didn't write these poems. Welcome to your downfall in a legal suit if you really are serious about pursuing profiting from stolen content.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't work that way, @Souta. I'm not planning to gain any profit over this, and they agreed on the terms by posting.

Comment: @Bane As long as you state your source for the words used, I then think you wouldn't have a problem. (If you don't state your source, like not mentioning 4chan, even with the terms, it still counts as plagiarism.) --Just saying.

Comment: Any sources on that? Because if someone agreed to a verbal contract by writing a post, I don't see how I would have any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real limit on what can be published, and I don't think vulgarity is a barrier on poetry (in some markets, sure, but far from all).

The question is who exactly you're aiming this proposed book at. Is it a humor/gift item ("The Poetry of 4chan!")? Or is this serious, "artistic" poetry? Or perhaps, as you mention, it's a sort of character study - delving into the psyches of these writers and trying to say something about them as a group (in which case you might want some additional material, perhaps viewing these 4chan sociopaths from several different angles and not just the possibly-oblique poetry).

If you want to pitch this book, you'll have to have a good, clear proposal, because otherwise this could easily wind up with a "why the hell would I want to publish random ramblings from people who post obscene pictures on the internet?" reaction.

(Of course, publishing's an iffy prospect, doubly so for oddball projects. Even if it's possible, it's not gonna be easy.)

Comment: You could put them up as a 99-cent ebook. I think you'd sell a decent number of copies that way.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, what are you waiting for?

Go to http://kdp.amazon.com/ and publish it right now. Log in, paste it into the form, fill out the book details and click submit.

Amazon deletes you? Try Barnes and Noble. Go to http://pubit.barnesandnoble.com/. Follow the three simple steps.

Barnes and Noble deletes you? Try Feedbooks. Go to http://www.feedbooks.com/help/self-pub-howto/. Follow the four publishing steps.

Feedbooks deletes you? At that point buddy, you're really fighting the tide. Consider doing a personal blog. http://www.blogger.com/ You might even get some Adsense revenue that way.

Answer (score 1):

In my country there are publishing houses which publish "highbrow" experimental poetry, often with very brutal descriptions and vulgar language, and one of such books that has appeared this year (2013) contains some "4chan-isms". But, due to the local context, such stuff occupies a lot more of the poetry scene, I guess, than in other countries where really pop poetry can easily get away with it - maybe I'm incorrect, but that is my impression, that there are more poetry readers and, therefore, more interest in things types of poetry that are not experimental. So you may have to rely on self-publishing after all (if you don't manage to find a publishing house that promotes exactly this kind of poetry).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a publisher if you keep racial slurs for amusement in. Indeed, if you self-pub with that, you may well find yourself removed from vendors. Anything else goes, though. Go search on Amazon for PETS WITH TOURETTE'S...

(Also, I doubt very much this comes under "radical" ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned earlier- anything can be published.

If the real question is will a publisher pay you anything to publish it-The answer is will enough people pay money for the work to allow the publisher a chance to get a ROI? Need I mention that the market for poetry is not large?

Unless the work is really well-written and has some redeeming value I probably wouldn't be tempted to buy it even if it was self-published - based on your description.

If you think it is something that others will BUY then send query letters to agents and see if anyone is interested enough to represent you. If you don't come up with a really GOOD query letter I'd be willing to bet the only group who might make any money will be the postal system (when you send query letters and copies) and they are losing money. (Yeah, I know email is free but you'll have to try every agent and some still don't use the net.)